# autoLink="web" is not working when using setOnTouchListerner on TextView

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a TextView where i want the links to be clickable earlier it worked fine with autoLink = "web", but ever since I've implemented **setOnTouchListener** on it the links are not clickable, They still get highlighted though.

Here is my xml

```
<TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/currentime"
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/add_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textColor="@color/darkTextColor"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />
```

And here is the **setOnTouchListener**

```
holder.usermessage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
 private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
   Log.d("TEST", "onDoubleTap");

   ChatMessage chatMessage = messages.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
   String usermessage = chatMessage.getMessageText();
   String username = chatMessage.getMessageUser();
   String replytext;
   if (usermessage.contains("\n\nReply:\n")) {
    replytext = usermessage.substring(usermessage.lastIndexOf("Reply:\n") + 6);

   } else {
    replytext = usermessage;
   }
   if (replytext.length() >= 30) {
    cutstring = replytext.substring(0, 40) + "...";
   } else {
    cutstring = replytext;
   }
   String finalreply = username + ": " + cutstring + "\n\nReply:\n";
   ((ChatRoom) context).setReplyText(finalreply, username);
   return super.onDoubleTap(e);
  }
  // implement here other callback methods like onFling, onScroll as necessary

  @Override
  public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
   super.onLongPress(e);
   Log.d("TEST", "longPressed");
   ChatMessage chatMessage = messages.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
   String usermessage = chatMessage.getMessageText();
   copyMessage(usermessage);

  }
 });

 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  Log.d("TEST", "Raw event: " + event.getAction() + ", (" + event.getRawX() + ", " + event.getRawY() + ")");
  gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
  return true;
 }
});
```

What I have noticed is the links start working as soon as I change the return statement in **onTouch()** to **false** but the other methods start misbehaving they all respond to single tap and trigger **onLongPressed()**

Please help me if anyone has any idea how to make all of this work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason but **onTouch** method was interfering with links being clickable. I fixed this issue by Overriding **onDown** method and returning true in it. These are the changes made:

1. Changed **onTouch** to

```java
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

2. Added **onDown**

```java
@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
 return true;
}
```

Hope it helps someone else.